# Why isn't the express session cookie being stored on the browser's cookie storage on production, but it works on localhost?? (express + react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, express-session

I created a test react app which is deployed at vercel and the server is at render.com.
To solve cross-site cookie problems I set the same domain on both (app.mydomain.online for the app, and api.mydomain.online for the API). Now, when i look at the cookie in the header, no errors are showing up. However, The cookie still not getting stored.

server is created via npm init.
react is created via npm create-react-app.

this is my sample code.

server

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://app.myDomain.online',
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
    credentials: true
}));

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }
}));

app.get('/createSession', (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = 'user';
    res.send('new session is created');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('get sess')
});

app.get('/getSession', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.user){
        res.send('active');
    }else{
        res.send('not active');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

react

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

function Test() {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(' https://api.myDomain.online/createSession',
                  { withCredentials: true }
        );
    }, []);
    
    

    return (
        <div>Test</div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: So do you actually have an issue in your code or is it just that you can't see the cookie in your dev tools?

Comment: The code is running without an error. I can see the cookie in the dev tool with no error. The only problem is that it is not being stored in the browser's storage make it not able to load the session from the server when refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution a few days ago, It turned out that the cookie was being blocked was because its domain was too similar to the server's. I was able to fix the it by removing the api from the cookie's domain as cookie: { domain: '.domain.com' }. This is my new code bellow.

```
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const APP_SESSION = session({
    secret: 'secrete',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: 'session',
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
        maxAge: oneDay,
        domain: '.domain.com'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for express-session](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#cookieexpires)...

> **cookie.expires**
>
> Specifies the `Date` object to be the value for the `Expires Set-Cookie` attribute. **By default, no expiration is set, and most clients will consider this a “non-persistent cookie”** and will delete it on a condition like exiting a web browser application.

The docs go on to prefer the `maxAge` property to control this. Choose a time frame that makes sense for your application. For example, 1 week...

```js
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true, sameSite: "none", maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  })
);
```

Comment: For me, I had to include `app.set("trust proxy", true);` before `app.use(session...)` or else it does not work. My frontend and API are hosted on 2 different domains.